# jquery datatable : Export Multiple Header

Tags: datatables

I'm using the most recent version of DataTables 1.10.10 and Buttons 1.1.0. I'm trying to generate PDF and Excel files or Print view but I'm just getting one of the Header row,only the second one..

Here is the table:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan='4'>User</th>             
                <th>Start </th>
                <th>Basic</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
```

I have created a js fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/rfb93mqs/12/

Is it possible to export report with multiple header.

Comment: did you figured this out? i have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> No sorry. There is no option to export multiple headers in Buttons.

([Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29745/multiple-row-headers-export-in-pdf-excel-or-print)).

So apparently no official way ATM...

However, you could use `customize` in [excelHtml5](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) options, discussed [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36045/excel-export-add-rows-and-data) + [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xevpdeo1/12/)

Comment: any update on this after 3 years? still no multiple header export?

Answer (score 0):

datatable not support this function.

-use custome export library or function

Comment: This is considered a comment